# Nearest matching text search using the same table in ClickHouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

```
CREATE TABLE DB.table
(
    `date` Date,
    `path` String,
    `visits` UInt64,
    `users` UInt64
) ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM( `date`)
ORDER BY  `date`
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```

Insert Data

```
INSERT INTO DB.Table (`date`,`path`,visits,users) VALUES ('2022-04-01','sofa',14837,12444);
INSERT INTO DB.Table (`date`,`path`,visits,users) VALUES ('2022-04-01','regalo',11917,8268);
INSERT INTO DB.Table (`date`,`path`,visits,users) VALUES ('2022-04-01','puertas',7498,6279);
INSERT INTO DB.Table (`date`,`path`,visits,users) VALUES ('2022-04-01','armario',7078,6230);
INSERT INTO DB.Table (`date`,`path`,visits,users) VALUES ('2022-04-01','sofa-cama',6771,5442);
INSERT INTO DB.Table (`date`,`path`,visits,users) VALUES ('2022-04-01','sofas',6182,5161);
INSERT INTO DB.Table (`date`,`path`,visits,users) VALUES ('2022-04-01','tractor-cortacesped',5740,3407);
INSERT INTO DB.Table (`date`,`path`,visits,users) VALUES ('2022-04-01','cocina',5634,4721);
INSERT INTO DB.Table (`date`,`path`,visits,users) VALUES ('2022-04-01','sillas',5448,4738);
INSERT INTO DB.Table (`date`,`path`,visits,users) VALUES ('2022-04-01','silla',448,478);
```

I want get the nearest matching text for each `path` field using the same table

[I read this example](https://presentations.clickhouse.com/meetup26/new_features/#21), but in this case "clickhouse" isn't a value of the same table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do understand that it's a cross join and in case of 10 rows, it's 100 ngramDistance calls ?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    arraySort([t1.path, t2.path]) AS pair,
    ngramDistance(t1.path, t2.path) AS dist
FROM t AS t1, t AS t2
WHERE t1.path != t2.path
ORDER BY dist ASC

Query id: 3cdeb2af-3628-4289-9d83-91d571aa70e7

┌─pair────────────────────────────────┬───────dist─┐
│ ['silla','sillas']                  │        0.2 │
│ ['sofa','sofas']                    │ 0.33333334 │
│ ['sofa','sofa-cama']                │ 0.71428573 │
│ ['sofa-cama','sofas']               │       0.75 │
│ ['puertas','sillas']                │          1 │
│ ['sofas','tractor-cortacesped']     │          1 │
│ ['cocina','sofa']                   │          1 │
│ ['sillas','sofa']                   │          1 │
│ ['silla','sofa']                    │          1 │
│ ['puertas','regalo']                │          1 │
│ ['armario','regalo']                │          1 │
│ ['regalo','sofa-cama']              │          1 │
│ ['regalo','sofas']                  │          1 │
│ ['regalo','tractor-cortacesped']    │          1 │
│ ['cocina','regalo']                 │          1 │
│ ['sofa','tractor-cortacesped']      │          1 │
│ ['regalo','silla']                  │          1 │
│ ['armario','puertas']               │          1 │
│ ['puertas','sofa-cama']             │          1 │
│ ['puertas','sofas']                 │          1 │
│ ['puertas','tractor-cortacesped']   │          1 │
│ ['cocina','puertas']                │          1 │
│ ['armario','sofa']                  │          1 │
│ ['puertas','silla']                 │          1 │
│ ['armario','sofa-cama']             │          1 │
│ ['armario','sofas']                 │          1 │
│ ['armario','tractor-cortacesped']   │          1 │
│ ['armario','cocina']                │          1 │
│ ['armario','sillas']                │          1 │
│ ['armario','silla']                 │          1 │
│ ['puertas','sofa']                  │          1 │
│ ['sofa-cama','tractor-cortacesped'] │          1 │
│ ['cocina','sofa-cama']              │          1 │
│ ['sillas','sofa-cama']              │          1 │
│ ['silla','sofa-cama']               │          1 │
│ ['regalo','sofa']                   │          1 │
│ ['cocina','sofas']                  │          1 │
│ ['sillas','sofas']                  │          1 │
│ ['silla','sofas']                   │          1 │
│ ['cocina','tractor-cortacesped']    │          1 │
│ ['sillas','tractor-cortacesped']    │          1 │
│ ['silla','tractor-cortacesped']     │          1 │
│ ['cocina','sillas']                 │          1 │
│ ['cocina','silla']                  │          1 │
│ ['regalo','sillas']                 │          1 │
└─────────────────────────────────────┴────────────┘
```

Comment: "You do understand that it's a cross join and in case of 10 rows, it's 100 ngramDistance calls ?"

Yes, but I use it only once a day and I don't know other way becouse to use a python script will be more complex.

Thanks!

Comment: Ok Denny, you are right, when I use this with real data show me error limit exced
"Received exception from server (version 22.4.5):
Code: 241. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: Memory limit (for query) exceeded: would use 46.57 GiB (attempt to allocate chunk of 33554496 bytes), maximum: 46.57 GiB. (MEMORY_LIMIT_EXCEEDED" 

Any idea how I could perform this (or similar) SQL?

Is there any way to execute the SQL even if it takes a long time?

Comment: How many rows in the table?

Comment: 400.000 rows aprox, 
Maybe is better using python script + Executable Pool?

Comment: try `max_block_size=1000`

Comment: doesn't work, using this query

"SELECT DISTINCT
    arraySort([t1.path, t2.path]) AS pair,
    ngramDistance(t1.path, t2.path) AS dist
FROM database.table AS t1, database.table AS t2
WHERE t1.path != t2.path
ORDER BY dist ASC
LIMIT 100
SETTINGS max_block_size = 1000"

"Progress: 443.18 thousand rows, 12.50 MB (3.19 thousand rows/s., 89.89 KB/s.)  49%
0 rows in set. Elapsed: 139.849 sec. Processed 443.18 thousand rows, 12.50 MB (3.17 thousand rows/s., 89.39 KB/s.)"

Progress never exceed 49%..